# Creating duplicated data frames with different ID

Tags: r

I have a question for the community and hoping for some help.

I am trying to duplicate a data frame like the one below:

```
  ID   Time   Solve 
  1       0       1
  1       2       2
  1       4       3 
  1       6       1
```

I am trying to duplicate the above data frame 100 times so, it would read as below:

```
  ID   Time   Solve 
  1       0       1
  1       2       2
  1       4       3 
  1       6       1
  2       0       1
  2       2       2
  2       4       3 
  2       6       1
  3       0       1
  3       2       2
  3       4       3 
  3       6       1
  4       0       1
  4       2       2
  4       4       3 
  4       6       1
  .....
  100       0       1
  100       2       2
  100       4       3 
  100       6       1
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this or a resource to read up on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replicate`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, df1, simplify = FALSE))
out$ID <- as.integer(gl(nrow(out), nrow(df1), nrow(out)))
```

---

Or another option is `rep`

```
out <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 100),]
out$ID <- as.integer(gl(nrow(out), nrow(df1), nrow(out)))
```

---

Or make use of `uncount`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
uncount(df1, 100) %>%
       mutate(ID = as.integer(gl(n(), nrow(df1), n()))
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1 %>% 
   nest_by(ID) %>%
   uncount(100) %>%
   mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
   unnest(c(data))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Time = c(0L, 2L, 4L, 6L
), Solve = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```